# How to lunch Swiftmailer inside a button function

Tags: php, symfony, twig, swiftmailer

I'm using swiftmailer bundle, everything works good, but I still cannot integrate swiftmailer with my function.
I have to confirm users after registration "using a confirm button" and i want to instantly launch a confirmation mail to my user confirmed.

My Button's code in twig:

```
{% if r=='USER' %}
    <td>
        <a href="{{ path ('confirm_user',{id:user.id}) }}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Confirmer </button>
        </a>
    </td>
{% endif %}
```

---

My confirmAction in controller:

```
public function confirm_userAction($id)
{
    if (False === $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $this->render('@Admin/controlDerreur/denied.html.twig');
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository("MyAppUserBundle:User")->find($id);
    if ($user != null) {
        $user->addRole('ROLE_LECTEUR');
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('users_list');
}
```

---

My Mail controller:

```
class MailController extends Controller{
    public function indexAction(Request $request){
        $mail = new Mail();

        $form = $this->createForm(MailTypeForm::class, $mail);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Accusé de réception')
                ->setFrom('mail@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($mail->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView('MyAppUserBundle:Default:mail.html.twig',array(
                        'nom' => $mail->getNom(),
                        'prenom' => $mail->getPrenom()
                    )),'text/html');

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_app_mail_accusm'));
        }

        return $this->render('MyAppUserBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    public function succesAction()
    {
        return new Response("email envoyé avec succès, Merci de vérifier votre adresse mail.");
    }
}
```

---

My routings :

```
my_app_mail_newm:
    path:     /newm
    defaults: { _controller: "MyAppUserBundle:Mail:index" }


my_app_mail_accusm:
    path: /succesm
    defaults: { _controller: "MyAppUserBundle:Mail:succes" }
users_list:
    path:   /admin/userlist
    defaults: { _controller: "AdminBundle:Admin:list_users" }
confirm_user:
path:   /admin/confirm/{id}
defaults: { _controller: "AdminBundle:Admin:confirm_user" }
```

Comment: Your routes don't appear to show a route for `confirm_user`. Can you run `php bun/console debug:router` to confirm if it exists?

Comment: sorry it already exists  ||                                                   
-confirm_user:
    path:   /admin/confirm/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: "AdminBundle:Admin:confirm_user" }

Comment: Does the above code work? I mean - what happens when you click on the `Confirmer` button? Also try appending `app_dev.php` to your URL for debugging environment. Check your logs in the `var/logs' folder.

Comment: yes it works, it changes the status of the user account from user (his account is not already activated) to a member (his account was confirmed by the admin ) who must get a mail after the confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use a `SubmitType` button:

```
->add('sendmail', SubmitType::class, array(
   'label' => 'Send Email',
   'disabled' => true,
))
```

Then you can use `disabled` option to disable submit using Twig IF `{% if r=='USER' %}` to enable the submit button in your template.

**EDIT #2:**

So if all you need to do is send an email, modify your `confirm_userAction` controller:

```
if ($user != null) {
    $user->addRole('ROLE_LECTEUR');
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Accusé de réception')
                ->setFrom('mail@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($user->getEmail())
                ->setBody("My message");

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);

return $this->redirectToRoute('users_list');
```

Is that what you needed?

Comment: i'm not using a FormType , i'm just using a button in twig that when i click takes me to confirmAction which is supposed to change the status of a normal user to a reader, so i want to enable the mail in the same time to informe my user that his account has been confirmed

Comment: I've edited my answer. See if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: thx a lot,  your changes inspired me so i had to make some modifications in my code